# Able to Remove Header,Footer from PDF but while removing page number ex: 1/1 in this able to remove 1 but still / is appearing end of the file

Tags: java, html, css

After parsing the html, using below code to remove header, footer, and page number

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.head().appendElement("style").append("@media print {@page {margin: 0;} body {margin: 1.6cm;}}");
```

It's removing header and footer properly but issue while removing page number(1/1) partially removing page number but still not removing / from the pdf.

Please suggest better way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Issue got Resolved:)  

@media print {@page {size: auto; margin: 0mm;}body {background-color:#FFFFFF;margin: 1.6cm;}}

now / had removed from pdf file.